# LocationProvider Timeout in BlackBerry 6.0?

Tags: java, blackberry, geolocation

I use the follwoing code to get the Location data

```
Criteria csCriteria = new Criteria();
        csCriteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        csCriteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        csCriteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        csCriteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);

LocationProvider provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(csCriteria);
            Location location = provider.getLocation(-1);
```

the code works on BB 5.0 but now im testing it on BB 6.0 but it get **LocationException** with this msg **Timed out while waiting for GPS Location** (i use BB Torch on ATT , i have internet connection and GPS/Location is on) any idea why im getting this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to get the GPS without timeout error using this Criteria.

```
criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

criteria.setCostAllowed(true);

criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
```

For an example on how to get the GPS location for BlackBerry 6.0 [click here.](http://www.feras.us/post/3183571901/gps-location-for-blackberry-6-os)

Comment: I have the same issue but I'm not sure what the problem is - what's the difference between the criteria set above and this one?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Criteria documentation your specifications will result in Cellsite mode. I suspect ATT is not providing Cellsite support.

Comment: Also when i use GPS code it give me the same exception (i tried Cellsite and it works in ATT BB 5.0 but not in ATT BB 6.0)